# How to round when you have a mix of numeric and character in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, rounding, digits

After some statistics, I have a final data frame `Measure` containing 2 columns `Mean` and `Sd`.

We can easily merge `Mean` and `Sd` into a single column `Mean_Sd`:

```
Measure = Measure %>% 
  unite(Mean_Sd, Mean, Sd, sep = " ± ", remove = FALSE)
```

```
Size    Mean    Sd                                   Mean_Sd
1       0.025 0.000                               0.0253 ± NA
2       0.049 0.000                               0.0492 ± NA
3       0.009 0.000                               0.0089 ± NA
4       0.027 0.000                               0.0266 ± NA
5       0.046 0.000                               0.0463 ± NA
6       0.196 0.178     0.195966666666667 ± 0.177617576082249
7       0.143 0.000                                0.143 ± NA
8       0.052 0.002               0.0522 ± 0.0015556349186104
9       0.013 0.002               0.0128 ± 0.0019672315572906
10      0.052 0.000                               0.0524 ± NA
...
```

But now, how can I round (avec 3 digits) each value in the column `Mean_Sd` ? This column is a mix of character and numeric.

I've tried the following function but in this case, only the `Mean` and `Sd` columns (numeric) were effectively changed.

```
Measure <- data.frame(lapply(Measure, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) round(y, 3) else y))
```

Comment: why not round using `sprintf` before calling `unite`?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.  Include sample data using `dput`.